# Infinite p-groups with no normal subgroups.

Tags: gr.group-theory

A finite $p$-group $G$ always has a non-trivial center. However, there exist infinite $p$-groups with trivial center, see for example this question [Simple(st) example of an infinite $p$-group with trivial center](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49349/simplest-example-of-an-infinite-p-group-with-trivial-center). My question is do there exist such infinite $p$-groups with trivial center that contain no finite normal subgroups? More generally, does there exist an infinite $p$-group $G$ such that infinitely many elements of $G$ are not in $Z(G)$ and such that $G$ has no finite normal subgroups?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group . I assume that by "no finite normal subgroups" you mean "no finite nontrivial normal subgroups".

Comment: Note that Tarski monsters referenced by Martin are also 2-generated and simple. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The group $G$ described in " [Simple(st) example of an infinite $p$-group with trivial center](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49349/simplest-example-of-an-infinite-p-group-with-trivial-center) " is in fact an ICC group. This means that every non-trivial element $g\in G$ has an infinite conjugacy class. As a consequence, $G$ has trivial center (because the conjugacy class of an element in the center contains only one element), and no finite normal subgroups (because every normal subgroup is a union of conjugacy classes).

The group $\mathbb{Z}/p\wr(\mathbb{Z}/p)^\infty$ is also an ICC (infinite conjugacy classes) p-group, so its center is trivial and it can not have finite normal subgroups.

Comment: Thanks! What does that vertical squiggly line mean in the second example?

Comment: it means "wreath product".